# Trouble with upper bounded generics

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I'm having some trouble with a class that contains a member that uses generics. Consider the following sample classes:

```
class BaseRequest {
    // Content goes here
}

class SubRequest extends BaseRequest {
    // IFace methods go here, etc.
}

// Simple datastructure interface
interface Structure<T> {

    List<T> getElementsList();


    Collection<T> getDependencies(T t);
}

// Simple structure implementation, details unimportant
class StructureImpl<T> implements Structure<T> {

    @Override
    public List<T> getElementsList() {
        // Implementation details not important
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public Collection<T> getDependencies(T t) {
        // implementation details not important
        return null;
    }
}
```

I then have the following class that uses a Structure

```
class StructureUsingObject {
    final Structure<BaseRequest> structure;


    public StructureUsingObject(Structure<BaseRequest> structure) {
        this.structure = structure;
    }


    public void foo() {
        for (BaseRequest request : structure.getElementsList()) {
            Collection<BaseRequest> requests = this.structure.getDependencies(request);
            // do things
        }
    }
}
```

By itself, this won't work;

```
public void foo() {
    StructureImpl<BaseRequest> baseImpl = new StructureImpl<BaseRequest>();
    StructureUsingObject baseStruct = new StructureUsingObject(baseImpl);

    StructureImpl<SubRequest> subImpl = new StructureImpl<SubRequest>();
    // Compile error on this line
    StructureUsingObject subStruct = new StructureUsingObject(subImpl);
}
```

This makes sense; StructureImpl<BaseRequest> is not actuall a subclass of StructureImpl<SubRequest>. So, I try modifying the StructureUsingObject to use wildcards:

```
    class StructureUsingObject {
    final Structure<? extends BaseRequest> structure;


    public StructureUsingObject(Structure<? extends BaseRequest> structure) {
        this.structure = structure;
    }


    public void foo() {
        for (BaseRequest request : structure.getElementsList()) {
            // Compile error on this line
            Collection<BaseRequest> requests = this.structure.getDependencies(request);

            // To clarify, a compile error would happen here as well; the issue isn't with the return type
            this.structure.getDependencies(request);

            // do things
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either;

```
The method getDependencies(capture#4-of ? extends BaseRequest) in the type Structure<capture#4-of ? extends BaseRequest> is not applicable for the arguments (BaseRequest)
```

OK, that makes sense too, although the autocomplete tooltip doesn't (it states that getDependencies should have (null t) as its arguments). I'm not really sure where to go from here. I can't use a wildcard within the foreach. How can I satisfy the requirement that my StructureUsingObject can accept Structures with subclasses of BaseRequest, but while also being able to call getDependencies with elements from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapt your last version to capture the wildcard.

```
public void foo() {
    bar(this.structure);
}

private <T extends BaseRequest> void bar(Structure<T> s) {
    for (T request : s.getElementsList()) {
        Collection<T> requests = s.getDependencies(request);

        // do things
    }
}
```